# chrome extension background script confirm message title

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup

I have a chrome extension. In its background script I want to present a confirm() dialog box to accept (Ok/Cancel) input from user. Have no problem doing that.

The only problem is that the title of message shows up as "chrome-extension://32_char_extension_id". Not what I want to see. 
On the other hand in the safari extension (global.html) the title shows up as the "Extension name". 
Would be nice to have the same functionality in Chrome Extension.

Any idea if there is a way to see extension name in the message box instead of the ID. 
Anything I"m doing it wrong ?

I understand confirm() is the not the recommended solution for prompt to take user input (as it is a blocking call). But this seems like a quicker solution for what I"m doing.
The other alternatives I"m looking into using JQuery message boxes. But if I can resolve this thru simple confirm(), it would be great for now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should use the chrome.notifications API to display the dialog so that you ask the user something in this case. You can show a notification which has two buttons by like the following code:

```
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener((notificationId, buttonIndex) => {
    // If buttonIndex == 0, Ok button clicked.
    chrome.notifications.clear(notificationId, wasCleared => { ... });
});

chrome.notifications.create("notificationId", {
    type: "basic",
    iconUrl: "SOME_ICON_PATH",
    title: "YOUR_EXTENSION_NAME",
    message: "SOME_MESSAGE",
    buttons: [
        {
            title: "Ok"
        },
        {
            title: "Cancel"
        }
    ]
});
```

Of course, you need to get a "notifications" permission from the user.

Comment: Except notifications disappear in a few seconds.

Comment: @yoichiro thanks for responding. I'll try this out. Can use this notification in Background. And does the notification disappear as Xan was pointing out ?

Comment: @Yoichiro Looks like these notifications are desktop notifications. Right ? I"m looking something on the browser itself. Preferably a modal dialog. Can these notifications be customized to achieve that.

Comment: Oh, you guys are right. the notification will be closed in a few seconds... I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `window.confirm()` title, it is for anti-phishing.

You should try other approaches such as [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: thanks for response. This requires adding JQuery files to the chrome extension. Right ?

Comment: I think that the Bootstrap Modal can't be used because nothing is any displaying pages in this case. The background page never be shown.

Comment: @YoichiroTanaka, sorry I didn't catch the "background script" words in the previous post, however, since the author was using `window.confirm()` in the past, I think any other UI should do the same

Comment: @Feru, yes, but you can also implement your own modal using css + js. However, as Yoichiro mentioned, why do you want to show a dialog in background scripts? It shoule work in background and not be visible.

Comment: @Haibara Ai : The confirm has to be visible to the user. Calling confirm() in background script does bring up the message box.

Comment: @HaibaraAi:  Why confirm() in background ? Popping up confirm() in content script blocks the navigation of page (as it is a blocking call). In BG it works fine. Basically a quick solution for what I want to achieve.